# Creating java package on ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, packages, command-line

I am new to java. Here I am trying to create java package. And try to compile it from another directory . But there is an error like bash: `/home/gaurav/Desktop/package2/B.java: Permission denied`

Here is My first code and directory is /home/Desktop/package/A.java

```
package package1;
public class A
{
interface A1
{ void show();
  void display();
}
}

class B extends A
{
 public void show()
{
System.out.println("This is show method()");
}
public void display()
{
System.out.println("this is Display metthod()");
}
}
```

For compilation I did this command it's works fine. 
Working Directory is /home/gaurav

> javac /home/gaurav/Desktop/package/A.java

When I try to compile B.java which is in my Other drive

> /media/gaurav/iPlay/package/B.java

```
package package2;
class B
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("Reached in Main method of B");
    package1.A Object = new A();
}
}
```

I tired this vommand (grom previous working directory)

```
javac -cp /home/gaurav/Desktop/;/media/gaurav/iPlay/package/B.java
```

*Error Comes*

```
javac -cp /home/gaurav/Desktop/;/media/gaurav/iPlay/package/B.java 
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
bash: /media/gaurav/iPlay/package/B.java: Permission denied
```

What i am doing wrong? Please it my assignment I am not able to move further without this. I changed permissions.

Comment: `it my assignment I am not able to move further without this` -- Have you tried asking your instructor?  It may have been covered in one of the classes, or something that *should* have been covered (and asking him or her will help make for a better course for future students).

Comment: Classpaths are separated with a colon (:). The semicolon is used by the shell to delimit commands which is why in your output it shows javac executing followed by the permission denied error when it tries to execute /media/gaurav/iPlay/package/B.java

Comment: @MichaelT I tried asking from my instructor, but they said , we don't help you with Ubuntu , we can only help you with Windows . And about asking on stackoverflow , and not able to ask question on stackoverflow , that's why I asked here .

Comment: @Gaurav_Java Programmers.SE and SO have different scope - a question that is for one is rarely appropriate for the other.  P.SE is about design questions - patterns, data models, algorithms, and the more 'abstract' questions.  Questions about tooling (invocation of java, ant, make, etc..) and specific code errors are for Stack Overflow and not P.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are making some basic mistake
First is in class B

```
package package2;
class B
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("Reached in Main method of B");
    package1.A Object = new package1.A(); // Here package1.A
}
}
```

Second change package folder name according to there package name
e.g. :

> /media/gaurav/iPlay/package2/B.java
>
> /home/gaurav/Desktop/package/A.java

Then compile A.java (Assuming you are in root dir)

> javac /home/gaurav/Desktop/package1/A.java

Then B.java

```
javac -cp /home/gaurav/Desktop/package/ /media/gaurav/iPlay/package2/B.java
```

To execute this

> java -cp /home/gaurav/Desktop/:/media/gaurav/iPlay/ package2.B

i think this should work.